# How do I verify if several attributes are in a JSON structure within JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, validation

I am creating a module that takes in several complicated JSON files and would like some code to give the user feedback if certain elements are absent.

Below is the way I am doing it now, but I cannot help to think there must be a cleaner, less hacky way.

```
var _und = require("underscore");
//this function takes a list of required attributes and ensures they are present
var check_req_attr = function(config, req_attr, callback) {
    var config_attr = Object.keys(config);
    var absent_attr = _und.difference(req_attr, config_attr); //slightly hacky code that checks to ensure config has correct vars
    if (absent_attr.length !== 0) {
        throw Error("missing following attributes from config:" + absent_attr);
    } else {
        callback();
    };
};
```

It just feels...dirty.  If there is no real elegant way to do it, I would be open to critiques on my code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Parse the JSON to JS.

   `var data = JSON.parse(theJson);`
2. Use something like:

   ```
   function hasKey(obj, key) {
       return typeof obj[key] !== 'undefined';
   };



   function hasKeys(obj, keys) {

       for (var i = 1, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
           if (!hasKey(obj, keys[i])) {
               return false;
           };
       };
       return true;
   };
   ```

Now you can simply do:

```
if (hasKeys(data, ["firstKey", "secondKey", "thirdKey"]) {
    console.log("valid");
};
```

Comment: Note that this won't work with hierarchy. For example, you cannot use this method to test for `a.b.c` unless your intention is that they key is specifically called `b.c` rather than the normal "b is a subobject of a, and c is a key of b".

Answer (score 1):

This should be the way to do it, using [`every`](http://underscorejs.org/#every) and [`has`](http://underscorejs.org/#has):

```
if (_und.every(req_attr, function(attr) {
    return _und.has(config, attr);
}))
    throw new Error();
```

In a native environment, you would just use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

```
req_attr.every(function(attr){ return attr in config; })
```

Comment: @alex23: What is inconsistent with that operator? Why is it misleading? It does exactly what is wanted, checking for a property to exist.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is actually quite elegant! No need for an anonymous function, and the loop (which must happen at some point, obviously) neatly abstracted away with `difference`.

Two suggestions:

1. I'd give the function a synchronous signature. No callback argument. There can't be any reason to go async if you honor the function signature (i.e. basing your answer on `config` and `req_attr` only).
2. I'd change the function to return the missing properties (attributes is wrong term). You could also add a `requireProperties` function that uses this "check" function that would throw if a property was missing. This allows for different kind of uses.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with something like:

```
obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

and then check

```
if(obj.YourProperty == undefined){
    //do something..
}
```

Hope i understood your question.. It should work with complicated JSON files too.. Good luck ;)

Comment: sorry checking multiple properties

Comment: If you are checking multiple properties into a hierarchy, you could simply override my "if" with a function which goes through the parsed JSON Object..

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `in` operator (`requiredAttr in obj`):

```
function objHasAllRequiredAttrs(obj, attrNames) {
  return attrNames.reduce(function(memo, attrName) {
    return memo && (attrName in obj);
  }, true);
}

objHasAllRequiredAttrs({foo:1}, ['foo']); // => true
objHasAllRequiredAttrs({bar:1}, ['foo']); // => false
```

Comment: Why `reduce`? There's `every` for exactly that use case.

Comment: @Bergi: another answer already mentions `every`, I wanted to provide another option, just for diversity.  Also, I didn't see "underscore.js" in the tags so I wanted to stick to pure JS.